# Yii2 load attribute of a referenced table

Tags: model-view-controller, yii2

I'm working with Yii2 to create an application. Consider a model A that has an attribute with an external reference to another model B (both of them have DB tables) by id. When I populate the view of the model A I need to show an attribute of the object B referenced which is not the id. By now I create a variable in the model A that is populated during the afterFind() by querying the db for the attribute relative to the id of the model B. Is there a better way to solve this problem that does not require to use afterFinds or more variables? Can you provide an example?

Comment: Can't you just do something like `$modelA->modelB->modelBField`?

Answer (score 1):

I think your solution is not the better way.

You can look at  [this tutorial for sample](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/621/filter-sort-by-calculated-related-fields-in-gridview-yii-2-0/) about calculated and related field.

essentially you should do these step

1 ) Setup base model

```
 /* ActiveRelation */
public function getModelB()
{
    return $this->hasOne(TableB::className(), ['id' => 'country_id']);
}

/* Getter for ModelB Field name */
public function getModelBField() {
   return $this->modenB->name;
```

}

2 ) if useful  Setup search model

3 ) Setup view file

```
echo GridView::widget([
   'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
   'filterModel' => $searchModel,
   'columns' => [
     ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],
     'id',
     'yuorField',
    'modelBName',
    ['class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn'],
  ]
 ]);
```

Look at the detail in the sample  for a complete explanation